# In Javascript why '\-' === '-' evaluates to true? And is dash (-) an escape character in js strings?

Tags: javascript, escaping

Same as title:

In Javascript why '\-' === '-' evaluates to true and not result in an invalid escape sequence error? And is dash (-) an escape character in js strings?

See codepen:

```
'\-' === '-'
```

http://codepen.io/puttyman/pen/kXxJXv

Comment: No, `-` is not an escape character, but `\` is. The `\` is redundant here as the hyphen doesn't need to be escaped. As you've noted, the resulting strings are equal.

Comment: I was expecting it to result in an 'invalid escape sequence' error.

Comment: to actually escape the character you need to use double backslash, `'\\-' == '-'; //false `

Comment: Superfluous character escapes in javascript is not an error, just superfluous. It's a very forgiving language. The only way to produce an error that I can think of is `\u` and `\x`which will expect a unicode and hexadecimal escape character, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

It is not only for dash `-` 
The backslash () is an escape character in Javascript.
when you write `'\checkit'` the backslash doesn't escape any special characters as there is not any.

so statement `'\checkit' === 'checkit'`

will always return true

Answer (score 0):

Dash `-` is not a escape character but `Backslash (\)` is a escape character

So `'\WhatEver' === 'WhatEver'` will always returns **true**

Please have a look at 
[Special Characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yfce773(v=vs.94).aspx)